# Is page cache a part of Java Off heap memory?

Tags: java, apache-spark, memory

JVM has on heap and off heap memory.
If a java proc write a file to the disk(not in Direct_IO mode), the os will cache the file in memory as page cache, I'm curious if the page cache is a part of JVM offheap memory?

The background is I'm running a scala Spark job in K8S . It get OOM killed frequently even if I set the memory overhead to 0.2. According to the Spark UI, the peak on-heap mem + off-heap mem is much smaller than the container memory limit. But according to `dmesg` the java proc take all the memory of the container at the time it was killed.
So I'm wondering if it's page cache who takes the rest of memory and cause the java proc being killed?

According to the SparkUI, the dead executor1 on take 21.1 GiB (on heap) + 142.2 MiB (off heap) memory.
[spark ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXb0P.png)

But according to dmesg, at the time it was killed, it takes much more memory as SparkUI said.

```
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:35 2023] memory: usage 25907200kB, limit 25907200kB, failcnt 1911352
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:35 2023] memory+swap: usage 0kB, limit 9007199254740988kB, failcnt 0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:35 2023] kmem: usage 106724kB, limit 9007199254740988kB, failcnt 0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:35 2023] Memory cgroup stats for /kubepods/pod320ce7f2-aa63-4f3f-9fbe-2ae0be48736c:
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:35 2023] anon 25102856192
                           file 1315708928
                           kernel_stack 1069056
                           slab 52314112
                           sock 0
                           shmem 0
                           file_mapped 0
                           file_dirty 1316130816
                           file_writeback 0
                           anon_thp 20558381056
                           inactive_anon 0
                           active_anon 25102508032
                           inactive_file 328622080
                           active_file 987414528
                           unevictable 0
                           slab_reclaimable 43982848
                           slab_unreclaimable 8331264
                           pgfault 11556633
                           pgmajfault 0
                           workingset_refault 814704
                           workingset_activate 165
                           workingset_nodereclaim 0
                           pgrefill 12258140
                           pgscan 15669889
                           pgsteal 2556626
                           pgactivate 13111197
                           pgdeactivate 12258004
                           pglazyfree 0
                           pglazyfreed 0
                           thp_fault_alloc 11253
                           thp_collapse_alloc 0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:35 2023] Tasks state (memory values in pages):
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:35 2023] [  pid  ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:35 2023] [ 168097] 65535 168097      241        1    28672        0          -998 pause
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:35 2023] [ 168142]     0 168142      571      192    49152        0          -997 tini
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:35 2023] [ 168217]     0 168217  7542445  6135546 50069504        0          -997 java
```

Call Trace

```
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023] Call Trace:
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  dump_stack+0x57/0x6d
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  dump_header+0x4f/0x200
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  oom_kill_process+0xec/0x140
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  out_of_memory+0x117/0x570
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  mem_cgroup_out_of_memory+0xbb/0xd0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  try_charge+0x762/0x7c0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  ? ext4_do_update_inode+0x4ff/0x7b0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  mem_cgroup_try_charge+0x75/0x190
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  __add_to_page_cache_locked+0x21a/0x3d0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  ? scan_shadow_nodes+0x30/0x30
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  add_to_page_cache_lru+0x4f/0xd0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  pagecache_get_page+0xea/0x2c0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  grab_cache_page_write_begin+0x23/0x40
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  ext4_da_write_begin+0x11a/0x450
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  generic_perform_write+0xb3/0x1b0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  __generic_file_write_iter+0x1aa/0x1d0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  ? generic_write_checks+0x68/0xc0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  ext4_file_write_iter+0xbd/0x360
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  ? futex_wake+0x8f/0x180
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  new_sync_write+0x125/0x1c0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  __vfs_write+0x29/0x40
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  vfs_write+0xb1/0x1a0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  ksys_write+0xa7/0xe0
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  __x64_sys_write+0x1a/0x20
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  do_syscall_64+0x5e/0x200
[Mon Feb 20 03:36:55 2023]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
```

Comment: The OOM killer doesn’t care which process the memory belongs to. All it matters, is that the memory is full. And surely, the operating system will drop caches first, before killing applications, don’t you think? So it’s very unlikely that I/O caches are the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Holger. Yes, I think os should drop the cache first. but according to the call trace in dmesg. For  most of the time, the java proc was killed when it tried to operate page cache. So I doubt whether the oom is related to the I/O cache.

Comment: It tries to perform a write operation and requires a buffer. The os can drop all caches, except the buffers for an ongoing I/O operation.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @JoachimSauer updated. Thanks for correctting me.

Comment: @Holger If the java proc is heavily writing data to the disk. Thus the disk buffer is filled. Is it possible that the file piled in page cache, waiting for write back to disk and thus the page cache can be released, so that the java proc take much more memory for page cache?

Comment: *I'm curious if the page cache is a part of JVM offheap memory?* - `file_dirty 1 316 130 816` (1.3 GB) vs. `142.2 MiB (off heap)`. My random guess would be a "no".